Comparing assessment methods in longitudinal design
I am currently trying to figure out what to do but I can´t seem to find a proper solution.
My problem is the following:
I have a longitudinal design. For each day I have a variable stating whether an event occurred (1) or did not occur (0) and a variable to be answered in a 5 point Likert scale. This assessment was primarily done by phone (ecological momentary assessment). Unfortunately, sometimes the phone broke down and the participants filled out the different variables with a paper-pencil-form. That mean now I have for only a few participants for only a few days no phone but a paper assessment. I want to see whether I can merge those assessment methods together into 1 dataset. This means: Do the answers given to the questions differ based on the assessment method?
But I have several difficulties: First of all, I only have a handful of paper assessments. Second, I have 4 groups which have different lengths in assessment periods (some have 16 days other 24 days). Third, I have varying number of days missing for the participants. Some have only 1 or 2 days missing in the phone assessment, some even more. When phone is missing only a few have a paper form and consequently paper is also incomplete for the time periods.
I came up with the following options but I am very unsure:

Regression model: DV is mean across all measured days per person of the probability of an event occurring. Then I have a variable depicting the number of days assessed per person (without missings) and another variable with how long the assessment period was (as that differed between groups). Then I could merge both method datasets together and have another variable for paper vs phone assessment and see whether this one is significant.
Weighting: I could use inverse weighting per day and thus calculate the mean and probability per person and compare both assessment methods with a t-test.
Mixed-method regression: For random effects maybe random intercept and slope. Fixed effects could be number of days with entry and length of assessment period and maybe some other variables.

Thanks in advance. I am struggling and nobody in my vicinity can help.

If it were possible to jointly rank all the possible answers merging the two media then you could do a longitudinal ordinal analysis on a single outcome scale.  Is that sensible for your setting?
